# Why pixel data is modified when i open an image with PIL.Image.open?

Tags: python-3.x, image

I am creating a new image with Image.new from PIL, where `data = [(0,1,0)]*12`, then i use `imag.putdata(data)` method and finally i save it as 'sample.jpg' using `img.save`. It turns out that when i open 'sample.jpg', function `getdata` returns all pixels with value 1, when in fact i saved it with some null pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems correct. You made an image in which the pixels were each 0% red, 0.5% green and 0% blue, and saved it as a [lossy JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression). The JPEG-encoder, which *tries to optimise photographs* and is perfectly at liberty to change your data, decided that looked pretty much like black and saved it as such to save space.

Here are your image (enlarged) and a black one for comparison:

[image] [image]

If you want lossless image saving, you'll need to use a lossless format such as [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Comment: Then it cant be done steganographic images using j.pg right? Thanks i undertand

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you want your data bit-perfect, you need lossless.